# FileNotFoundException in a Spring Boot application with JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, filenotfoundexception

In my Spring boot webapp I am trying to implement some backend functionalities to generate PDF files using `JasperReports`.

I have a file structure looking like this:

[image: File structure]

The app, when running, has no problem in seeing the `application-*.properties`, or any files in `static` folder.

I have written a piece of code to just generate the report and show it in `JasperViewer`:

```
    JasperPrint print = null;
    try {
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("invoices/invoice.jrxml");
        print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("invoices/invoice.jasper", new HashMap<>());
        JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(print);
        jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when I'm trying to run the app, all I get is:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: invoices/invoice.jrxml (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `java.io` file api operations to load the resources from the classpath. It works when the application in unpacked  during development in IDE but will fail when the app is packaged to JAR, hence the `FileNotFoundException`

Change your code to load the resources from the classpath with `InputStream` e.g. by using [`JasperCompileManager.compileReport()`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperCompileManager.html#compileReport-java.io.InputStream-):.

```java
try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/invoices/invoice.jrxml")) {
    JasperCompileManager.compileReport(in);
    ...
}
```